# Cropping a rectangle out of a larger image

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

I'm using a variation of code I found on another stackoverflow question to crop a rectangle out of a larger image at a specified location. But every time it crops it get the correct width and height but the image shows up black.

[How to crop an image in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725489/how-to-crop-an-image-in-vb-net)

*face is a predefined rectangle object.

```
Dim OrignalImage = Image.FromFile("C:\fileName.jpg")

            Dim CropImage = New Bitmap(face.Width, face.Height)
            Using grp = Graphics.FromImage(OrignalImage)
                grp.DrawImage(OrignalImage, OrignalImage.Width, OrignalImage.Height, face, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
                OrignalImage.Dispose()
                CropImage.Save("C:\newfile.jpg")
                grp.Dispose()
            End Using
```

Comment: It looks like you're creating your `CropImage` object with the desired size but never telling your `DrawImage()` to apply the image to it. So when you save `CropImage` its just blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating your `Graphics` object from `OriginalImage`. You need to be creating it from your `CropImage`.

Also, you don't need to call `grp.Dispose()` because the `Using` block will do that for you.

Corrected code:

```
Using OrignalImage = Image.FromFile("C:\fileName.jpg")
Using CropImage = New Bitmap(face.Width, face.Height)
    Using grp = Graphics.FromImage(CropImage)
        grp.DrawImage(
            OrignalImage, 0, 0,
            face, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    End Using
    CropImage.Save("C:\newfile.jpg")
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Your use of `DrawImage` may be incorrect as well, but it's impossible for me to tell without more information. What are you trying to do? You have a large image (fileName.jpg) and a rectangle in that image (face) and you're trying to create a new cropped image (newfile.jpg) that contains the specified portion of the source image? Try my edited code if this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! One last question if I wanted to expand the area of the rectangle slightly, where would I make that adjustment? To `face.width` and `face.height`?

Comment: To put padding around the face? Yes, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: I actually just tried that and it just added white space, maybe i need to add it to the face object because its used in `grp.drawimage`?