# How to crop and resize image using vb.net and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, picturebox

I'm using vb.net and sql server 2008 and a picturebox for uploading photos. 
This is what I want to do.

1.The image can be anything. It can be bitmap,jpg,png, anything
2. upload image from my computer
3. Crop the image and resize it to fit in my picture box.
4. Save it to the SQL Server database

This is my working code for uploading and saving images in the database.

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim a As New OpenFileDialog

 Private Sub PictureBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.DoubleClick
        Dim picl as string
        a.filter = nothing
        picl = a.filename
        a.showdialog()
        picturebox1.image = image.fromfile(a.filename)
 End Sub

 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
 cn.Open()
    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspAdd", cn)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@customerPic", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Save Record New record Successfully")
            End Using
cn.close
End Sub
```

I have read some reference here but it does not work for me and now I'm stuck for almost an hour.
This is what i have tried.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
    Public Class Form1
    Dim a As New OpenFileDialog
    Private Sub PictureBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.DoubleClick
        Dim picl As String
        a.Filter = Nothing
        picl = a.FileName
        a.ShowDialog()
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(a.FileName)
        Dim OriginalImage = Image.FromFile(a.FileName)
        Dim CropRect As New Rectangle(100, 0, 100, 100)
        Dim CropImage = New Bitmap(CropRect.Width, CropRect.Height)
        Using grp = Graphics.FromImage(CropImage)
            grp.DrawImage(OriginalImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, CropRect.Width, CropRect.Height), CropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            OriginalImage.Dispose()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Can someone please help me to fix my code. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's not working...can you be specific? Why do you have `Dim a As New OpenFileDialog` twice? If you're gonna crop the image in the picturebox, use that image when you add it to your DB instead of the original image file.

Comment: @chase Rocker sorry `dim a as New OpenFileDialog` is only declared once. i Fix the code above.  I read this [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725489/how-to-crop-an-image-in-vb-net) but i can't apply it with my code. Can you help me with my problem?

Comment: You don't understand a specific line of code or you don't understand any of it? If you don't understand any of it, you'll probably want to read up on .net Graphics functionality...trying to explain it is too broad of a topic here.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Anyway, Can you give me some sample code on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can crop image and designate the path and the name of cropped image with the following code sample , anyway ur sql fucntion needs  image file path

```
  Dim LocX = 100 'x cord. of where crop starts
    Dim LocY = 0 'y  cord. of where crop starts
    Dim CropW = 100 'Crop width
    Dim CropH = 100 'Crop height
    Dim CropRect As New Rectangle(LocX, LocY, CropW, CropH)
    Dim OriginalImage = PictureBox1.Image
    Dim CropImage = New Bitmap(CropRect.Width, CropRect.Height)
    Using grp = Graphics.FromImage(CropImage)
        grp.DrawImage(OriginalImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, CropRect.Width, CropRect.Height), CropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        CropImage.Save("cropped file path and name here")
    End Using
```

Comment: Hi, i did it this way [Code](http://pastebin.com/h4jYmdnA) but it throws me error `A generic error occurred in GDI+ ` in this line  `CropImage.Save("C:\Users\agent_edx44\Pictures")`

Comment: GDI+ error says you "You have no auth. to save this file into this directory". You have to type the filename too like "C:\Users\agent_edx44\Pictures\asdf.jpg"

Comment: The error is still the same when i type the filename too. Here is my [screenshot](http://img0.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/22369/22369880cc6b83f87f8381f54eef8c26c6f44f63.jpg)